# Passing markup into a template with xsl:with-param

Tags: xslt

I have the following xslt template:

```
<xsl:template name="with-newlines">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap" white-space-treatment="preserve">
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to apply the template with xsl:call-template on an element:

```
<xsl:call-template name="with-newlines">
    <xsl:with-param name="text">
        <fo:inline font-size="8pt">
            <xsl:value-of select="./Foo/Bar"></xsl:value-of>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

However, the fo-inline tag is ignored in the resulting pdf-file. If I put the tag in the template itself, I get the correct fontsize. But then I cannot use the template in places where the font-size (or other attributes) needs to be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<xsl:copy-of select="$text"/>` instead of `value-of`.